# How to notify a linux (systemd) process to take action, when a file is created

Tags: file, process, systemd

Not sure where to start on the above question.

I have systemd process (A) running with some file handling capabilities.

The requirement is to notify (A) when a file is created by another process (B) at a certain location (say /tmp/abc.txt).

Upon receiving the notification, (A) can open the file and do its parsing/caching and close it. I believe we can queue the requests if (A) is already processing something.

Is this requirement even possible? If yes, is there a traditional/systemd design pattern to go about it? If not, can this be achieved in any alternate way?

Comment: Would inotify (or the inotifywait command) be useful to you?

Comment: This does not appear to be programming related.

Comment: @Tesseract: Thank you. I think inotify seems to be close to what I am looking for. Let me explore in that direction.

Comment: @Alnitak: I believe anything to do with APIs or design patterns is programming related. I might be wrong. You can down vote my question if you feel so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `inotify` API, as Tesseract mentioned, or employ a systemd path unit (which also uses `inotify` under the hood):

```
# foo.path
[Path]
PathExists=/tmp/abc.txt

# foo.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/A
```

Note that this will *start* `foo.service` each time the file is created, not notify it. From your question it’s not clear to me if that’s okay for your case or not – if you want to do some operation on the file and then do nothing until the next time the file pops up, that should be fine (exit from the service and set `Type=oneshot` in that case).

Comment: Thanks Lucas. This seems like a nice alternative to inotify. Let me explore both options and see which would be the more cleaner and flexible approach.